# InfluxDB - Drop series is not working

Tags: influxdb, grafana-templating

I want to delete some hosts that I'm not using anymore because show up on grafana with templates and I don't want that.

I execute `drop series from measurement where host = 'hostName'`
Then I execute `show series from measurement`

The host still there. Any idea?

```
drop series from cpu where host = 'hostName'
show series from cpu where host = 'hostName'
cpu,cpu=cpu-total,host=hostName
cpu,cpu=cpu0,host=hostName
cpu,cpu=cpu1,host=hostName
```

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using?
There seems to be a bug with the newer versions (1.4+) not dropping data:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/9246

Comment: Yes, that could be. I have 1.4.2.
Post as an answer to give you your points. 

This is weird, apt update does not retrieve the new version and was released a month ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug with the newer versions (1.4+) not dropping data: github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/9246

The bug was fixed, so you should upgrade your installation.

Install and start the InfluxDB service (older linux dist):
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install influxdb
sudo service influxdb start

If your operating system is using systemd (Ubuntu 15.04+, Debian 8+):
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install influxdb
sudo systemctl start influxdb

For full documentation:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/introduction/installation/

Answer (score 3):

In some later version of influx another bug (behavior) exists - after dropping all series by tag you should restart influxdb server to reset/cleanup/rebuild some in-memory data. In my case hosts disapeared only after restart.
See this issue later discussions for more details: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5092

Comment: I can confirm this is happening on v1.7.4 on macOS. Had to restart InfluxDB to reflect the drops.